# Rewrite search url in wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried several different .htaccess solutions as well as plugins, but nothing seems to be working.  I have different links that use an url like this on my Wordpress site:

`http://www.mydomainname.com/?s=&post_type=schools&general_search=1&general_search_term=Science`

How would I rewrite those urls to look like:
`http://mydomainname.com/search/science` in the browser?

Thanks!

Here is what I have in the .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /?s=&post_type=schools&general_search=1&general_search_term=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply way

```
function ctheme_search_url() {
  if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
      exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'ctheme_search_url' );
```

You can use wordpress redirect functions

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /?s=&post_type=schools&general_search=1&general_search_term=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**EDIT:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /?s=&post_type=schools&general_search=1&general_search_term=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What's the exact URL did you try in your browser and what error you got?

Comment: This is what I have: 
    
    <pre><code># BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ /?s=&post_type=schools&general_search=1&general_search_term=$1 [L,QSA,NC]


    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress</pre></code>

Comment: Can you post this .htaccess in your question pls?

Comment: Can you try .htaccess in my EDIT section above.

Comment: But it not only brings up a different template, but not all of them work.  For example:  http://www.degreescape.com/search/Health%20Care%20Administration doesn't work, but the link in the sidebar on the home page does.

Comment: http://www.degreescape.com/search/Health+Care+Administration works fine. For spaces you can use plus sign `+`

Comment: Ah..I see.  But its using the archives template and not the search template when I do that..?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about templates.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

http://wpengineer.com/2258/change-the-search-url-of-wordpress/

```
# search redirect
# this will take anything in the query string, minus any extraneous values, and turn     them into a clean working url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

Dont forget to add anything before  `/search/` to match the url you have.

Comment: Answering in links is discouraged in Stack overflow. Provide the portion of that page that answers the question of OP in your answer so that future readers may be able to read it even if the link is broken.